# How to force python functions to work with UTF-8

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have problem with python function `os.path.isdir`

While I'm trying to use it I get: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)`

I've already placed coding "stamp" in the header of my file `#!/usr/bin/env python # coding: utf-8`

I also use rather proper string decoding that enables getting utf-8 signs (I load them by QT QLineEdit - but this does not matter).

```
tmp_filepath = u''
tmp_filepath = tmp_filepath.decode('utf-8')
tmp_filepath += QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Choose directory",self.directorypath,QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
```

Problem occurs while I'm trying to use: `os.path.isdir(tmp_filepath)`

I've read that this may be caused by bad python version (non utf-8) but I couldn't find other info about this. I use python 2.6.5 on Linux Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: You can't `.decode()` something that's already a `unicode` instance. What do you want the second line of your code to accomplish? Can you show the `repr()` of what you're actually passing to `os.path.isdir()`?

Comment: yes you are right - I forgot to delete this piece of code. And string that I am trying to pass is : etc/etc/Zablokowanie Uśpienia - I know that compiler "shouts" because of "ś"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isdir wants to convert its argument to a byte sequence (str) because the underlying file system uses byte sequences as file names.  If you supply a character string (unicode) it must encode it somehow.

It uses the same encoding rule that the print commmand would use.   Try print tmp_filepath and you will probably get the same exception.

To solve this problem, either (a) set your locale (e.g LANG=en_US.utf-8 in the environment) or (b) pass tmp_filename.encode('utf-8') to isdir and mkdir.

I recommend (a).

Answer (score 0):

Qt returns you a QString object - you have to trasform it to a Python unicode and encode it into utf-8:

```
 tmp_filepath = unicode(tmp_filepath)
 os.path.isdir(tmp_filepath.encode("utf-8"))
```

Also, be shure to read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
before proceeding with your programing today.

Alternatively if you don't have to interoperate with other text variables in Python, QString objects provide a `.toUtf8` method themselves:

```
os.path.isdir(tmp_filepath.toUtf8())
```

Comment: Problem is QT returns QString - it does not provide .encode(). And I also cannot use str() on it, because I get also unicode exception.

Comment: If you had read the article above, you'd be better at it and probably be able to guess that you can apply `unicode(   )  ` on a QString; I am editing the answer to reflect that. Please, read that article _before_ yu harm yourself and others trying to program i18n apps any longer.